# How to deal with "how to circumvent product limitations (intentionally imposed by product vendors)" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

What is the official policy towards questions asking for ways to circumvent the limitations intentionally imposed by vendors (mostly security related features) in their products?

The question that I personally come across most frequently is **how to achieve X on an Android without having to root my handset?** (**X** being different features specifically reserved by Google for Android system apps only)

Authors of such questions often already know the answer before asking but they are in denial and not willing to accept it.

**Update:**
After reading all the answers and comments I decided that I need to clarify it some more. While not completely uninterested in the ethical or even legal side of things - I was trying to focus on the extremely narrow scope of such questions. The vendors are relentlessly working on fixing the security holes exposed in their products - so most answers providing such information become obsolete in months if not weeks anyway.

Comment: Simple. If you know of an answer that works, then post it. If you know none exists, then post an answer explaining that none exists. If you don't know, then leave it alone. Same goes for any other question.

Comment: I think the official policy is along the lines of "we're not here to enforce vendors' rules for them; questions should be judged on their technical merits, and that's all".  I think the policy for dealing with questions that are too narrowly scoped to be useful is also consistent regardless regardless of _why_ the question happens to be narrowly scoped.  So in other words, deal with them in exactly the same way as any other question.

Comment: Closely related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent

Answer (score 15):

There is no need to treat "how to circumvent" questions specially.

The problem you see is that a particular question is often asked. But if the same question is often asked, there are already tools for dealing with that: you can close the questions as duplicates.

An even nicer option, that does entail more work on your part, but is also not specific to "how to circumvent" questions, is finding or creating a canonical question & answer for this. It seems like it would be beneficial to have an answer explaining that it's impossible, why it's impossible, and what the closest alternatives are that developers can consider using instead.

---

The above applies when you have one specific question that gets asked over and over, which is the impression I got from your question here. You clarified that the questions are subtly different in two ways:

Firstly, the "How do I do X in Android?" questions don't actually all have the same request as X. In that case, find a duplicate or find or create a canonical question & answer per feature.

Secondly, "How do I do X in Android 5.0?" isn't helped by closing it as a duplicate of "How do I do X in Android 4.0?". This is a bit trickier. *If* you have a good question & answer you would otherwise have closed it as a duplicate of, and if you know or can verify that the answer is still applicable, then it makes sense to make that question & answer less version-specific. Instead of asking  "How do I do X in Android 4.0?", change it to "How do I do X in Android?", and include a mention in the answer that it is correct up to (insert date here), which corresponds to Android 4.0. When the question then gets asked for 5.0, you can update the answer if it doesn't yet cover the current version, and *then* close the new question as a duplicate. With a polite comment, this shouldn't cause any issues. For example, "I know this wasn't a duplicate when you posted your question, but I updated the other question instead of posting an answer to yours."

Comment: I CVed as duplicates a few questions like that before. The response I often got (from the OP and other users) was "it is clearly not a duplicate. the Q you linked is about version X.Y.Z and this Q is about version X.Y.Z.1!". I am CVing them as "unclear" from now on.

Comment: Another reason why the "duplicates" approach is not optimal in my opinion is that such questions could be about many different issues. What links them together is the same answer - the vendor does not want you to be able to do this and even if you would be able to circumvent the limitation this time - most likely it will get fixed in the next version and the answer will become obsolete.

Comment: @AlexP. "How do I do X on Android?" and "How do I do Y on Android?" shouldn't be linked as duplicates, I agree with you on that. The impression I got from your question is that "How do I do Y on Android?" gets asked a lot. If the questions are actually about different features, then find one question per feature. As for different Android versions, that's actually a fair point. Will edit my answer to address that later.

Comment: -1 This answer misses the point of the question. Alex P. isn't asking how to handle a type of question that he sees duplicated frequently. He's asking what to do when someone explicitly asks how to do something that violates an EULA or the software manufacturer's intentions. As in, is it ethical for someone to ask those questions? Is it ethical or legal for us to answer them? Does the SO staff have a stance on the issue?

Comment: @Kevin I don't see anything about ethical consideration in the question. Indeed such questions are allowed on SO and there is nothing "illegal" about saying "this restriction is set by XXXX and can't be worked around without exploiting bugs that may or may not exist". This type of questions come all the time in all other tags - like bypass same-origin policy in browser or write to ACL-protected files in Windows, not really scoped down to Android.

Comment: @Kevin What Alexei Levenkov said. I didn't answer that, because I don't see it as relevant here. But I'll go a step further and say not only is there nothing illegal or inherently immoral about answering such questions as "You can't", there isn't even anything wrong with asking those questions. The typical person asking those questions doesn't understand the reason for those limitations, isn't trying to hack your phone, is just a developer trying to get a job done with no ill intent. We can help with that. Not the way that developer thinks, but help still.

Comment: I do custom Androids for custom hardware from time to time - it is *I* who am the platform builder in this case. I might still ask questions about bypassing a control or another because I want to keep the default limitations from Android in place, except for one or another exception for stuff that *has* to work on my device. So in a lot of cases, the question isn't about bypassing some security measure, but a normal developer question.

Comment: I think his main point is not even so much that it's "illegal" (it might be, but my understanding is that SO doesn't care unless it's absurdly blatant, like straight out asking how to scam people). I think his main point is that, because it's a request for how to get around an intentional software limitation in easily-patched software, any correct answers would be *quickly* obsoleted as the software is patched to prohibit that answer from working. Which is a reasonable point to make. But it would still be reasonable question, even if "you can't" is the correct answer, so people know that.

Comment: @Kevin - Yes, it ethical to ask, and to answer (correctly, I mean, and not just with a "you can't because the EULA").  Even if it wasn't, SO isn't a party to the asker's EULA  agreement and as such is not obliged to follow or enforce it.  The same may apply to the anyone who answers the question (knowing how to circumvent a vendor restriction doesn't necessarily mean you've ever had dealings or a EULA with that vendor), or even to the OP (perhaps they're engaging in idle speculation).  It's silly to make certain technically interesting topics verboten just because a vendor would prefer it so.

Comment: @AlexP. Well, what's the problem?  They aren't duplicates if they're about different versions.  They're also not really unclear.

Answer (score 8):

I'd answer the question stating that

A. it would need root access (and describing how it can be done with `su`)

or

B. it would need to be a system app (and describing what platform APIs can be used to solve the problem)

While I know that most of these questions are asked by developers who just want a simple app, a potential answer can be very useful for visitors, who are either platform builders (especialy as there are lots of undocumented APIs inside the platform), or don't mind that their app will only work properly with root access.

Comment: Edited my question to clarify that most of the questions I was talking about are being asked by 3rd party app developers who want to sell their system apps to general public and not just to very limited market share of handsets with custom builds.

Comment: @AlexP. still it's answerable technically, even if they wouldn't like that answer